# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database "Path" doesn't exist

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm newbie with python and django,

Im trying to setting up Django in windows7,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'amour'),
        'USER': 'openpg',
        'PASSWORD': 'openpgpwd',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

when trying to execute the server:  **python manage.py runserver**

the below error appear :**django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database "Path" doesn't exist**

I already install PostgreSql 9.3 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the **name** of the database, not the filename.  So if you [created database](https://superuser.com/questions/220771/how-can-i-create-a-database-in-postgresql-on-windows-7) named `"amour"` then setting will be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'NAME': 'amour',
        ...
    }
}
```